# Prove $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1\}$ is connected

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, connectedness

Definitions:

> Connected: Not separated
>
> Separated: If $C$ is a subset of a metric space, then $(A, B)$ is a separation of $C$ if $C = A \cup B$, $A \neq \varnothing$, $B \neq \varnothing$, and we cannot have that $\{x_n\} \in A$, $x_n \to x$, with $x \in B$ (and also vice versa).
>
> Path-connected (implies connected): A subset $S$ of a metric space is path-connected if $\forall p, q \in S$, $\exists$ a path $\Gamma \in S$ joining $p$ and $q$.
>
> Path: If $X$ is a metric space, $\Gamma \subset X$ is a path joining $p \in X$ and $q \in X$ if $\exists$ a continuous function $f: [0,1] \to X$ such that $f(0) = p$ and $f(1) = q$.

So if we *do* have a separation of $C = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1\}$, then we'll have $2$ non-empty subsets $A$ and $B$ of $C$ such that there are convergent sequences in $A$ that cannot converge to any point in $B$, or vice versa.

We have to show that this cannot happen, so if we take an arbitrary sequence of ordered pairs from one set, say $A$, we have to show that it can converge to an ordered pair in $B$ so that it means $C$ not separated, and thus connected. It feels like there's not much to work with here. What other information can I use to show this?

Comment: Do you already have the theorems that $[0,1]$ is connected and that the product of two connected spaces is connected? If so, you're done.  If not, then I'd concentrate on trying to prove those two theorems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Show $\;C\;$ is *path-connected* :

For any $\;0\le t\le 1\;$ and for any two $\;(x,y),\,(a,b)\in C\;$ , we have that

$$t(a,b)+(1-t)(x,y)\in C$$

Comment: We just learned path-connected today, but our definiton is different from this one so I don't think we're allowed to use your definition. But this problem was given before today when we learned about path-connected, so we shouldn't have to, but if path-connectedness makes the problem easier I'll use it

Comment: What definition of path connected you have? The above describes *a path* between any two points in the set.

Comment: The definition of path-connected I have is that there exists a path between any two points in the set.

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs Good: that's **exactly** what I produce in my answer.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how your definition of path-connected and our definition are equivalent

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs The last line in my answer **is** a path !

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize this. I thought you were providing a different definition of path-connected. So basically the function you gave is a path that joins any two arbitrary points in the entirety of $\mathbb{R^2}$, so it also applies to my subset and thus it's path-connected?

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs Yep, and it is thus connected.